# How to extend third party framework in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a third party framework (say **A**) for a task in my iOS app. The framework **A** has a class (say **C**) with some properties defined and I want to add some extra (my own) properties in that class. I want to access my defined properties after allocating the class **C**.

Can anyone provide me any idea for implementing this? Please also let me know if I have to explain more my requirement.

Thanks

Comment: This really has nothing to do with a 3rd party framework. Any possible solution would be the same for any class you might be using.

Comment: In objective c you can only add additional properties by creating a subclass of C

Comment: @Paulw11 You can also add properties through a category. The problem is that you can't add instance variables to back the properties using a category.